# Delete element from PHP array with a certain string

Tags: php, arrays, string, session

I have a string containing `4uCW6J9KQ8`.

I have a `$_SESSION` array containing that string as so:

`array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "4uCW6J9KQ8" [1]=> string(10) "SZQ5zuB3Yk" }`

I want to delete the element containing the string. Here is the code I have:

```
<?php
session_start();

$key=array_search('4uCW6J9KQ8',$_SESSION['ids']);

if($key!==false)
unset($_SESSION['ids'][$key]);
$_SESSION["ids"] = array_values($_SESSION["ids"]);

?>
```

But it is not deleting the index. Any ideas?

Comment: `$_SESSION['ids']` or simply `$_SESSION`

Comment: Is it actually deleting the index and failing to save it back to session again; or is it failing to delete the index?

Comment: Failing to delete the index

Comment: Then debug to check that it's actually finding the index

Comment: Im getting `Undefined index: variable,/home/samstone92/public_html/sam/deleteSample.php,3`. PHP is not my native tongue..

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['ids']` is set?

Comment: I set it with `<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ids'])){
   $_SESSION['ids'] = array();
}
?>`

Comment: It is the `unset` behavior in non-global scopes. Try `unset($GLOBALS['_SESSION']['ids'][$key]);`

Comment: @Deadooshka `$_SESSION` should be a super-global, always available everywhere

Comment: Why not just `array_slice()` that out?